# Is it safe to convert an Image field in Varbinary(MAX)?

Tags: sql-server

Is it safe to change field type from Image to Varbinary(MAX) in a sql-server database, knowing that it is used by several other softwares in my company ?
Is there a risk that other applications would not work properly ?
I only have access to the code of the application I am developping.

Comment: why don't you test it? (and by that I mean on something that's not production)

Comment: Of course there is a risk, that is why you must test. Chances are that everything would work just fine after the conversion, but you must test. Image type is deprecated in SQL Server anyway, so changing to varbinary looks like good idea.

Comment: I can test ONLY with the software I'm developping, I can't test with others sofwares that other developpers in the company develop, using this database. I tested with the software I'm developping, and it works fine, but before sending this on a production database, which will be used by other softwares, I wished to know if it was risky.